# deletions from SQL table results in many more rows removed than expected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of stock symbols in a database called `FINALDB`, some of which are also in the NYSE table. Lets say that i only have 3 distinct ticker symbols there.

I want to reference all rows in the `FINALDB.NYSE` table which match these 3 tickers and remove those rows and write them to a table in a different database. what is happening is that the rows are in fact getting removed, but I am getting 3x the rows expected. It's as if is is doing the deletion 3 times because there are three tickers in the `[FINALDB].[dbo].STOCKS` table. if I have 50 tickers in that table that match tickers in the NYSE table, I am getting 50x the amount of rows deleted as I am expecting. it's performing a delete operation for each occurrence of a ticker in the other table. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @currentDate date = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())

DELETE FROM FINALDB.dbo.NYSE
OUTPUT DELETED.Ticker, DELETED.Exchange,
       DELETED.[Date], DELETED.[Open],
       DELETED.[High], DELETED.[Low],
       DELETED.[Close], DELETED.[Volume],
       GETDATE() AS Delete_Date
INTO [STAGEDB].[dbo].Deleted_Data_Type5
FROM FINALDB.dbo.NYSE
INNER JOIN [FINALDB].[dbo].STOCKS ON [FINALDB].[dbo].STOCKS.[Ticker] = [FINALDB].[dbo].NYSE.[Ticker]
                                  AND [FINALDB].[dbo].STOCKS.[Exchange] = [FINALDB].[dbo].NYSE.[Exchange]
                                  AND [FINALDB].[dbo].STOCKS.[Date] = @currentDate
```

Comment: If you run that `DELETE` as a `SELECT` - do you get too many rows? Tweak your `SELECT` until you get the right set of rows - then convert it back to a `DELETE`

Comment: well, you have `output deleted`, just check your `deleted_data_type5` out and find what's wrong.

Comment: What happens if you alias both tables, then use the alias on the first line? Like `DELETE FROM n OUTPUT ... FROM dbo.NYSE n JOIN dbo.STOCKS s ON ...`

Comment: Thanks, i will try the suggestions and reply later.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the suggestion of changing it to a SELECT to compare results. I failed to include the top part of the script, which runs in python.
for ex in exchanges:

This was resulting in the Stock exchange (singapore) being referenced 3 times, one for each occurrence of the symbol in the table.
Name: Combined, dtype: object
0    SG
1    SG
2    SG

So, it was doing the delete operation over and over (how there was anything left to delete on subsequent runs escapes me)